# Why can't I add non react variables(state, props) such as normal variable, external functions in dependency array of useMemo?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

Please look at the commented code. Why can't I use name as dependency in useMemo?
I want to stop useEffect rerendering the page again just because some referential equality of a variable is changing that's why i used useMemo in themeVar object.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from "react";

const External = () => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  const [dark, setDark] = useState(false);
  const doubleNumber = useMemo(() => {
    return slowFunction(number);
  }, [number]);

  const themeStyles = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      backgroundColor: dark ? "black" : "white",
      color: dark ? "white" : "black",
    };
  }, [dark]);

//   const themeVar = useMemo(() => {
//       return {
//           name : 'parth'
//       }
//   },[name])

//   useEffect(() => {
//       console.log('new  object')
//   },[themeVar])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("theme chnaged");
  }, [themeStyles]);

  return (
      <>
    <input
      type="number"
      value={number}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setNumber(parseInt(e.target.value));
      }}
    />
    <button onClick={() => setDark(prevDark => !prevDark)}>Change Theme</button>
    <div style={themeStyles}>{doubleNumber}</div>
    </>
  );
};

function slowFunction(num) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
  return num * 2;
}

export default External;
```

Comment: is `name` a variable? You didn't declare anywhere in the component, that's why you might be getting the error.

Comment: actually that's the whole anonymous object which only contains property as name that's why i didn't declare that anywhere

Answer (score 0):

you didn't declared "name" anywhere in your code except themeVar dependency array also you can't use themeVar return object key "name" in dependency array